# Remove Curly lines from ID card

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-preprocessing

How can I remove lines similar to the one present in the picture(green in color on top of face)?

I have seen many methods to remove vertical or horizontal lines but here the lines seems to be curly and also i want to extract information from the image(i.e. the face image part)  post the removal of these lines and hence don't want the resulting image to be grayscale.

[Sample Image](https://i2.wp.com/www.zambianobserver.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/67248467_342189893351524_4344420721972215808_n.jpg?fit=960%2C539&ssl=1)

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: The picture is low contrast/low quality. Processing to remove the waves will worsen it, probably to a point that it becomes unusable.

Comment: I am using some DL based approaches to perform resolution enhancement of images.This is a sample image similar to my case that i found online, but the original set I have are of good quality.

Comment: IP questions cannot be answered without true samples.

Answer (score 0):

I enlarged the area without the curly lines.

[image]

Comment: Like I said, this is just a cropped part of another image(id-card) on which the lines go on top of important information and face images and hence want to see how can i remove them or something like this. Maybe I will just update the question a bit to give more clarity.

Comment: @SrijanSharma: indeed, your question is quite incomplete.

Comment: Okay let me update the sample image  in the question then.